# How does a faucet work?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, everyday-life

Well I mean how exactly water flows to the sink. 
How is it pulled through the faucet?

Comment: It, uh, flows downwards? Could you clarify what puzzles you?

Comment: I mean how pressure affects it because its "drained". It flows upward and then its thrown on the sink

Comment: You may want to add a sketch, because it's unclear why the answer is anything else but gravity causing pressure.

Comment: Well, the faucet is pressurized by a gravity feed and the sink works because it is vented somewhere. If you have ever seen plumbing that isn't properly vented you will be able to tell that it's VERY necessary.

Comment: Well as you can see English is not my native language. I mean how water is drained through the faucet. When you open valve then some force is shown and i want to understand this

Comment: The water is pressurised. See, e.g., http://www.ofwat.gov.uk/consumerissues/rightsresponsibilities/waterpressure/.

Comment: I edited your question slightly. I hope that captures it.

Answer (score 4):

If you live near the ground, at least in the United States, chances are the pressurizing force for your tap water comes from a [water tower.](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Water_tower) The weight of the water flowing down out of the tower pushes it through the faucet. Since the pressure is determined by the height difference between the tower and your faucet, which doesn't change much, your water pressure is fairly consistent.

Tall buildings rely on their own pumps to pressurize water and move it to upper levels, since they reach above the height of water towers. I believe most tall buildings do still contain water reservoirs of their own to help even out the pressure, and at least for fire suppression systems.